# Erro System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

eu estou com um problema no meu projeto, esta dando erro System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

Eu importei 2 Dll's para o meu projeto, mas aparece como se não estivesse.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe oque pode ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostra pra gente como está a lista das dependencias dos seu projeto, por gentileza.

Comment: Olá @Aline, Editei a pergunta e coloquei a imagem na mesma.

Comment: TMW.Base é um projeto na mesma solução?

Comment: @jbueno isso mesmo, o TMW.Base é um projeto na minha solução

Comment: Verifique a ordem de build, isso deve estar errado.

Comment: Habilita isso no seu Visual Studio - Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code (Managed only)

Comment: Consegui Resolver, Usei a ferramenta Dependecy Wlaker, e foi possível saber quais dependências estavam faltando. O visual Studio não deixou importar as dependências, então foi preciso fazer na mão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce precisa definir para copiar para a pasta local na hora do build

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Copy Local deve estar True